# Access variable from column 2 in Yii

Tags: php, yii

For example if i have:

```
$this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
```

How can i access the model variable within the context of column2.php?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example

Model.php

```
<?php
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $data=$this->loadModel($id);

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$data
    ));
}
?>
```

View.php

```
<?php
echo $model->xxxxSOME_MODEL_VARIABLExxxxxx;
?>
```

Comment: he wants to access it in the layout file column2.php